# "property not found on object of type" error in prepareForSegue trying to send parameters to the next Table View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Xcode doesn't seem to find the properties of a given UITableViewController even though I'm importing it and they seem correctly defined on the class.

I've tried to clean, delete derived data, restart XCode and build again, none of this works.
Also have tried to access the property through the setter.

This is my code:

**MasterViewController.m**

```
#import "DetailTableViewController.h"
...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nextScreen"]) {
    DetailTableViewController *detailTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    detailTableViewController.productType = tagIndex;

    /*[detailTableViewController setProductType:tagIndex];*/ //This does not work either.
 } else  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"anotherSegue"]){
    MyLoginViewController *loginViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    loginViewController.delegate = self; //Funnily enough, this one works
 }
}
```

**DetailTableViewController.h**
    #import

```
@interface DetailTableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSInteger *productType;
}

 @property (nonatomic) NSInteger *productType;

@end
```

**DetailTableViewController.m**

```
@implementation DetailTableViewController

@synthesize productType = _productType;
...
```

**edit:** The error comes into this line:

```
detailTableViewController.productType = tagIndex;
```

Does anyone have an idea about why could this happen?
Thanks!

**Updated:**

Looks like it's something related to how XCode is referencing my files, it's really odd:

- When I cmd + click on detailTableViewController (the one where I create my instance) it takes me to my actual code:

  ```
   detailTableViewController *detailTableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
  ```
- But when I cmd + click on the import line, it takes me to some interface with the same name as mine, and same declaration except it does not have any of the properties my code has.

  ```
  #import "DetailTableViewController.h"
  ```

Has anyone gone through the same issue?

Comment: Just wanted to highlight as well that when I create an object referencing DetailTableViewController, the autocompletion feature does not find any of the properties of that class, as opposite for LoginController where it finds the delegate property.

Comment: ok so you must have two classes with the same name floating around there, did you check that? that's why autocompletion would fail to find the class's properties too. check your file structure and make sure you don't have any duplicates

Comment: Thanks @jere , you were right and that's what happened, the file was twice on the filesystem for some reason, I realised that just after posting the update. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved!

So basically, I could find that there were two copies on the file within Finder, one on the root folder of my project and another one inside the source folder.

Can't come across why did this happen or whether I duplicated the file without intention, but now it's perfectly working.

Thanks to you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Name your detail controller something else than the class (pretty obvious).

```
detailTableViewController *detailTableViewController
```

for:

```
detailTableViewController *detailTable
```

Comment: Well, actually the naming convention I use in the code is not as I wrote it, so the name was already different hence this did not solve the issue, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the detailTableViewController embedded in a Navigation Controller?  If so, you'll need to access it this way:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nextScreen"]) {
    UINavigationController *nc = segue.destinationViewController;
    DetailTableViewController * detailTableViewController = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; // First view in nav controller
    NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    detailTableViewController.productType = tagIndex;
}
```

Comment: You are right on the Navigation Controller part, but I've tried this (with the right index, which is 1) but still does not work. It's also embedded whithin a tab bar controller.

Comment: Also, when I create an object referencing DetailTableViewController, the autocompletion feature does not find any of the properties of that class, as opposite for LoginController where it finds the delegate property. Thanks for your tip, anyway!

Comment: @mr-cairo I just updated with the odd behaviour XCode is having related to the issue, It would be much appreciated if you could have a  look and let me know your thoughts about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should cast `[segue destinationViewController]` to whatever type of controller you need, since that method returns a generic `UIViewController` (it doesn't know what type of class you want it to be, that's why you need to cast it)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"nextScreen"]) {

        // cast destinationViewController to DetailTableViewController
        DetailTableViewController *detailTableViewController = (DetailTableViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        NSInteger tagIndex = [(UIButton *)sender tag];

        detailTableViewController.productType = tagIndex;

    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"anotherSegue"]) {

        // cast destinationViewController to MyLoginViewController
        MyLoginViewController *loginViewController = (MyLoginViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        loginViewController.delegate = self;

    }
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work. On the second case (Login( it works perfectly with the delegate parameter, so I don't think that is the problem, but in any case it's a good convention to follow. Thanks!

Comment: could you post relevant code for your `DetailTableViewController` class?

Comment: Because of confidentiality agreements I am not allowed to disclosure the code in full, but as you can see it's just a TableViewController with three NSArray properties it makes use of (and they work) and now I need to add this NSInteger property. It still works perfectly within the app, but not when I try to send the parameter from the previous ViewController.

I'm not sure if it may have something to do, but I moved the code to a different location, and the DetailViewController it's inside a group, but MasterViewController and LoginViewController are not.